# How to make customize appbar with tabbar like that image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to achieve something like the following, and how to do that circle progress with colors.

That's my try using the stack widget

[image]

I'm not that professional at Flutter so I couldn't figure it out. I need a custom AppBar with a drawer and actions but arranged like the image.

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  initialIndex: 0,
  child: Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Home'),
            selected: _selectedIndex == 0,
            onTap: () {
              _onItemTapped(0);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Business'),
            selected: _selectedIndex == 1,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              _onItemTapped(1);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('School'),
            selected: _selectedIndex == 2,
            onTap: () {
              // Update the state of the app
              _onItemTapped(2);
              // Then close the drawer
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Total",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "7,560 EGP",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: secondryColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(20),
                )),
            // Background
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: const TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              indicatorWeight: 5,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              tabs: [
                Text(
                  "Total",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "7,560 EGP",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // Background
          ),
        ),

        Container(), // Required some widget in between to float AppBar

        const Positioned(
          // To take AppBar Size only
          top: 115.0,
          left: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: Card(
            color: mainColor,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
                Text("sad"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Can someone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: use sliverappbar

Comment: @MunsifAli but I don't understand how to make it with silverappbar

Comment: check the simple AppBar there is a bottom variable which can used for this type of functionality also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the tab bar in AppBar `bottom` property, add container with bottom radius to make appbar rounded effect and wrap it with Stack along with TabBarView as the tab content.

This is the simple workaround code to demonstrate: *(runnable in dartpad)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Text('Title', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                  Text('Subtitle', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                ]),
            bottom: const TabBar(
              dividerHeight: 0,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(text: 'main'),
                Tab(text: 'rain'),
                Tab(text: 'sun'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                          height: 200,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.yellow.shade100,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('sad'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text("It's rainy here", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    Text("It's sunny here", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the results:

[image: demo]

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much you were very right, I understood it wrong I thought it was only the app bar that contains the app bar and container